# SQL, rank for each instance of a partition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to to create a rank for each instance of a status occurring, for example

| ID | Status | From_date | To_date | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 3 |

For each `ID`, for each instance of a `status` occurring, by `from_date` ascending.

I want to do this as i see this as the best way of getting to the final result i want which is

| ID | Status | From_date | To_date | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 3 |

I tried `dense_rank(partition by id order by status, from_date` but can see now why that wouldnt work. Not sure how to get to this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with this CTE for the data:

```
with data(ID, Status, From_date, To_date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'Available',    '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02'),
        (1, 'Available',    '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'),
        (1, 'Unavailable',  '2022-01-03', '2022-01-10'),
        (1, 'Available',    '2022-01-10', '2022-01-20')
)
```

the first result, being rank can be done with [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html):

```
select *
    ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT( Status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY From_date ) as rank
from data;
```

| ID | STATUS | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 0 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 | 1 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 2 |

and thus the keeps the first of each rank can be achieved with a QUALIFY/ROW_NUMBER, because the CONDITIONAL_CHANGE is a complex operation, needs wrapping in a sub-select, so the answer is not as short as I would like:

```
select * from (
    select *
        ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT( Status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY From_date ) as rank
    from data
)
qualify row_number() over(partition by id, rank ORDER BY From_date ) = 1
```

gives:

| ID | STATUS | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 | 1 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 2 |

Also, the final result minus the ranking can be done with:

```
select *
from data
qualify nvl(Status <> lag(status) over ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY From_date ), true)
```

| ID | STATUS | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 |

and thus a rank can be added at the end

```
select *
    ,rank() over ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY From_date ) as rank
from (
    select *
    from data
    qualify nvl(Status <> lag(status) over ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY From_date ), true)
)
```

| ID | STATUS | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | Unavailable | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 1 | Available | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical gaps-and-island problem, where islands are groups of consecutive rows that have the same status.

Here is one way to solve it with window functions:

```
select id, status, 
    min(from_date) from_date, max(to_date) to_date,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by min(from_date)) rn
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by from_date) rn1,
        row_number() over (partition by id, status order by from_date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, status, rn1 - rn2
order by min(from_date)
```

This worked by ranking rows within two different partitions (with a without the status) ; the difference between the row numbers define the islands.

Answer (score 1):

You can group consecutive status using `conditional_change_event`, then collapse the dates using `min` and `max`, and finally use `row_number()` to rank the events

```
with cte as
(select *,conditional_change_event(status) over (partition by id order by from_date) as rn
 from t)

select id, 
       status, 
       min(from_date) as from_date, 
       max(to_date) as to_date, 
       row_number() over (partition by id, order by min(from_date), max(to_date)) as rank
from cte
group by id, status, rn
order by rank
```