# Split quarters to individual months

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table like below. The period column is of `varchar` type and indicates the year and quarter.

| PERIOD | YEAR | USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/03 | 2021 | 100 |
| 2021/06 | 2021 | 100 |

How can I split the period columns to months that make up the quarter and get the following output?

| PERIOD | YEAR | USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/01 | 2021 | 33.33 |
| 2021/02 | 2021 | 33.33 |
| 2021/03 | 2021 | 33.33 |
| 2021/04 | 2021 | 33.33 |
| 2021/05 | 2021 | 33.33 |
| 2021/06 | 2021 | 33.33 |

Comment: Hey, could you please provide the code that you are referring to?
Also, please provide an example of what you want to achieve (i.e. what are you converting from and what do you want to convert to)?

Comment: Is date the only column you have in your table?

Comment: @EcaterinaVidrascu Hello.. I have one Varchar type column with data like 2021/03, 2021/06, 2021/09 , 2021/12 (all these are quarter dates in format YYYY/QQ) and so on.. I need to convert each quarter date suppose 2021/03 to 2021/01, 2021/02, 2021/03 in 3 rows instead of one. This is similar to all the quarters. So need to convert the quarter date into a monthly one. so instead of one quarter row I need to get 3 rows with 3 months of that quarter.

Comment: @Rajat - No I do have other columns but I prefer to create a view or something. I have even tried out a Store Procedure using a for loop and if conditon, but the if clause is fetching me an error.

Comment: Please add some sample data that's representative of you actual table and expected output for it (in a table format) For e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306350/sql-rank-for-each-instance-of-a-partition/74309728#74309728

Comment: @Rajat Not able to embed any picture.. but I have given an example..

Comment: @Rajat yes Thank you for that.. Do you have any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tackle the date manipulation and leave the rest to you. I prefer using date functions instead of string manipulations in case I later decide to do something else with the dates

```
set period='2020/03';

select $period, to_char(add_months((replace($period,'/','-')||-'01')::date,-0),'yyyy/mm')
union all
select $period, to_char(add_months((replace($period,'/','-')||-'01')::date,-1),'yyyy/mm')
union all
select $period, to_char(add_months((replace($period,'/','-')||-'01')::date,-2),'yyyy/mm')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rajat. It worked and I was able to finish the other part too. You made my day. :)